# Friends email issue while getting from facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to get friends email addresses using facebook api like that

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions","read_stream", "email", "user_about_me", "friends_about_me", "friends_notes");

String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, contact_email FROM user WHERE uid IN " + "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()
{
    public void onCompleted(Response response)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "response: "+response);
    }
});
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

But I cant get success for email but ya i am getting other values. Any one have idea about that?

I also need to get contact numbers of friends. Is it possible? Also guide me for that.

Thanks

Comment: i dont know any permission for friends email (i think it was but is not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official docs:

> There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends.

For more details: [Email Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)